# how Delete a value in Array php

Tags: php, arrays

Please help 
when i want yo remove an element from array buu after when i print array it shows error 
4
6
2
NOTICE Undefined offset: 3 on line number 16

```
<?php
    $value = 22;
    $numbers = array(4, 6, 2, 22, 11);
    $arrlength = count($numbers);

    for($y = 0; $y < $arrlength ; $y++) {
        if ( $numbers[$y] == $value) {
            unset($numbers[$y]);
        }
    }
    $arrlength = count($numbers);
    for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
         echo $numbers[$x];
         echo "<br>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Arrays in php don't re-index when you remove a value so `$numbers[3]` will be undefined. Use a `foreach` to loop over the array or re-index manually using `array_values()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "array_values()" to re-index the array. You can find the explication here : http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.useful-funcs

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_values()`.

```
<?php
$value = 22;
$numbers = array(4, 6, 2, 22, 11);
$arrlength = count($numbers);

for($y = 0; $y < $arrlength ; $y++) {
if ( $numbers[$y] == $value) {
    unset($numbers[$y]);
}
}
$numbers = array_values($numbers);
$arrlength = count($numbers);
for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
echo $numbers[$x];
echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

**Check Online Demo : [Click Here](https://eval.in/561091)**

OR

```
<?php
$value = 22;
$numbers = array(4, 6, 2, 22, 11);
$arrlength = count($numbers);

for($y = 0; $y < $arrlength ; $y++) {
if ( $numbers[$y] == $value) {
    unset($numbers[$y]);
}
}
//$numbers = array_values($numbers);
//$arrlength = count($numbers);
foreach($numbers as $key=>$num) {
echo $num;
echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to print element of not existing key

try this:

```
<?php
$value = 22;
$numbers = array(4, 6, 2, 22, 11);
$arrlength = count($numbers);

for($y = 0; $y < $arrlength ; $y++) {
    if ( $numbers[$y] == $value) {
        unset($numbers[$y]);
    }
}
foreach($numbers as $k => $number)
    echo "key: ". $k . " value: ". $number . "<br />";
```